# Add decimal point to the last character

Tags: javascript

I'm writing something that pulls some data from the internet; the thing is that one of the keys from the object that I get has weight and height and well, they're not formatted; they're like a whole integer; now, for example; if I get a `weight` key with a value of `1000` that means that it is 100.0kg; not just 1000, same with the `height` but sometimes I can get something like `10` on `height` which is 0.99m or 1m; `100` is 10.0m and so on, so, my question is; what can I do here to format these values properly adding a `.0` to the final if the value doesn't have it and if it does have it just add the decimal point before the last character? I tried doing some `ifs` but they were hard coded and I looking very bad, plus it didn't work.

Output that I'm getting

Example:

```
Weight: 1000
Height: 20

Weight: 69
Height: 7

Weight: 432
Height: 12
```

Expected output:

```
Weight: 100.0
Height: 2,0

Weight: 6.9
Height: 0.7

Weight: 43.2
Height: 1.2
```

Comment: Can you divide the numbers by 10?

Comment: convert the numbers to string. if the length o the string is more than 1, remove the last character from the string, concatenate a dot, and reattach the last element. done

Comment: @AndrewMorton's solution seems the simplest

Comment: @AndrewMorton Wow, sometimes these problems with simple answers get past my head... thanks; yes, that was what I had to do.

Comment: Don't convert to string. You need the numeric type. 10 should transform to 1, which is equivalent to 1.0 (in JavaScript).

Answer (score 4):

You could divide by `10` and use [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for formatting a number.

> The `toFixed()` method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

```js
var values = [1000, 20, 69, 7, 432, 12];

values = values.map(function (v) {
    return (v / 10).toFixed(1);
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: @khuderm, but needed.